# Automatic value depending on drop down list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a drop list in D24, you can choose between Junior, Mid and Senior.

I want E24 to have a different value depending on the choice.
Junior= 21.43€ , Mid= 28.57€ , Senior= 35,71€

[image]

Then, I want to calculate my total amount depending on the number of people, rate and day. (people x rate) x Days

How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a formula with IF to display some results based on conditions.

```
    =IF(D24="Junior",21.43,
      If(D24="Mid",28.57,
        IF(D24="Senior",35.71,"Wrong entry (D column)")
        )
       )
```

> Then, I want to calculate my total amount depending on the number of people, rate and day. (people x rate) x Days

You can try to calculate by row, then sum the result.

First row `=(C24*E24*F24)`

Assuming there's 3 row : `=ARRAYFORMULA(C24:C27*E24:E27*F24:F27)`

Then sum everything : `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(C24:C27*E24:E27*F24:F27))`

Comment: I copy pasted the formula for the drop list and I get an error

Comment: Can you share what is the error ? What's the language of your sheet (formula will use ";" instead of "," based of country location) ? do you have any case sensitive issue ? (i.e. "Mid" =/= "mid") 
You can share a sample too, i'll be easier to fix issues.

Comment: I'm in France. Here is the sample: [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpO-ENN4v3PbmKqdV1bbQ5p42w4COLI1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm french too. There's two solutions : 

1/ Set your spreadsheet in english : Fichier > Paramètres de la feuille

Otherwise you can try this formula. 

2/ `=SI(D24="Junior";21,43;
      SI(D24="Mid";28,57;
        SI(D24="Senior";35,71;"Wrong entry (D column)")
        )
       )`
I've replaced the commas (",") with semicolons (";") in the formulas and for the values (like 35,71) replaced the (".") with (","). 

For reference with the same formula, 
French version will be like `=somme(12,3;14,5)`


English version will be like `=sum(12.3,14.5)`

Comment: My spreadsheet is set in english and it still doesn't work. Here is the sample : (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpO-ENN4v3PbmKqdV1bbQ5p42w4COLI1/view?usp=sharing) I still get a parse error

Comment: You're sharing a xlsx file. Are you using google spreadsheet or excel ?

Comment: Edit : i fixed your sheet https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jpO-ENN4v3PbmKqdV1bbQ5p42w4COLI1/view?usp=sharing